# Loop over vector exits with error Process finished with exit code -1073741819

Tags: c++, loops, vector

LE: In case it has any relevance i am using CLion. The program doesn't print anything.

I need to process a vector that contains vectors of string in the form of `name card_type` and display all cards in alphabetical order and the number of instances for each one. Output should look something like:

```
a_card 1
mastercard 4
visa 3
```

The code i have so far, that exits with error `Process finished with exit code -1073741819` . What is the issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void stats(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& vec) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> orderedCards;

    for (const auto& client : vec){ //scan database for cards and make ordered vector of pairs
        if (orderedCards.empty()){ //insert first pair to empty vector
            orderedCards.push_back(std::make_pair(client[1],1));

        }else{ //for each new client scan vector and add new client/increment counter
        
           for (auto pair = orderedCards.begin(); pair != orderedCards.end(); ++pair){
               if (client[1][0] < pair->first[0]){ //compare first letter of new client and existing client
                   orderedCards.insert(pair, std::make_pair(client[1], 1));// if its smaller, insert in front
                   break;// break iteration and go for next client

               } else if (client[1] == pair->first){ //if theyre the same, increment counter
                   pair->second+=1;
                   break;

               } else if (pair+1 == orderedCards.end()) //if end is reached, there was no existing client thus add new one with high letter
                   orderedCards.push_back(std::make_pair(client[1], 1));
           }
        }
    }
    
    for (const auto& count : orderedCards)
        std::cout<<count.first<<" "<<count.second<<std::endl; //print on each line card and counter

}

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> dataBase;


int main()
{
    dataBase={{"name", "bankcard"},{"name", "visa"},{"name", "bankcard"},{"name", "mastercard"},{"name", "bankcard"},{"name", "visa"}};
    
    stats(dataBase);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you run your code with debugger?

Comment: Im a beginner and dont really know how to use a debugger. Have tried putting a few breakpoints where i add pairs but cant really make sense of whats happening.

Comment: your crush is in the ` for (auto pair = orderedCards.begin(); pair != orderedCards.end(); ++pair) ` at the second iteration, you can see your code [here](https://onlinegdb.com/H1EEehWev) and you can debug it there

Comment: your core dumped happens because you are using iterators,  think what happens to iterator after you insert an element? [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert) read the section about validety

Comment: All pointers and referances are invalidated by reallocation. Should i use a range based for then? If so, i still need to find a way to account for the case when i need to add a pair to the end of the vector.

Comment: think about using find function or some variation of it, or you can use std::map, it comperator is using alphabetic order then insert will insert by order

Comment: this is the current output for you code?  `bankcard 3   mastercard 1  visa 3`  ?

Comment: It should be `visa 2` but right now untill i get a map version working it's not printing anything lol

Comment: Thanks, i updated the code with the working solution you suggested.

Comment: look at the answer that i posted

Comment: you can use vector<pair> insert of vector<vector<strings>>

Comment: i overly simplified the input to keep it short for this specific issue i had. it actually has 6 fields that get processed by different methods within a base and derived class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@xampierre here a simpler function without using std::sort and the algorithm lib

```
void stats(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& vec)
{

    std::map<std::string, int> orderedCards;
    for(auto & client : vec)
    {
        auto it = orderedCards.insert(std::make_pair(client[1],1));
        
        if (!it.second) // this means that the key was already in the map
            it.first->second+=1;
    }
    
   for (const auto& count : orderedCards)
        std::cout<<count.first<<" "<<count.second<<std::endl; //print on each line card and counter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @yaodav i switched from iterators to a map and sorting alg. Updated code with explanations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

bool compare(const std::pair<std::string , int>& pair1, const std::pair<std::string , int>& pair2){
    return pair1.first[0] < pair2.first[0];
}

void stats(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>& vec) {
        std::map<std::string, int> map;

    for (const auto& client : vec){ //scan database for cards and make map
        auto ret = map.insert({client[1], 1});// insert new key:value pair

        if (!ret.second) // this means that the key was already in the map
            ret.first->second+=1; // dereferance pointer to key to access value and +=1
    }

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> orderedCards(map.begin(), map.end()); // make vector of pairs (key, value)
    std::sort(orderedCards.begin(), orderedCards.end(), compare); // sort vector according to defined compare

    for (const auto& count : orderedCards)
        std::cout<<count.first<<" "<<count.second<<std::endl;

}

std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> dataBase;


int main()
{
    dataBase={{"name", "bankcard"},{"name", "visa"},{"name", "bankcard"},{"name", "mastercard"},{"name", "bankcard"},{"name", "visa"}};
    
    stats(dataBase);
```